# What does this python openpyxl "ValueError" mean?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, valueerror

I cannot identify why I am getting this error. Does anybody know what is the reason for such error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/g401428/Documents/Visual Studio Code/jackpotCalc/calculationFGTriggerProb.py", line 49, in <module>
    wb1 = load_workbook(excel_mb_path , read_only=True, keep_vba=False, data_only=True, keep_links=False)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 312, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 273, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 189, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 88, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 88, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 88, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 104, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.textRotation = int(textRotation)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 145, in __set__
    super(NoneSet, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Users\g401428\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 130, in __set__
    raise ValueError(self.__doc__)
ValueError: Value must be one of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88,
89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180}
```

I am getting this error with this code:

`excel_mb_path = "C:\\Users\\Book1.xlsx"`

`wb1 = load_workbook(excel_mb_path , read_only=True, keep_vba=False, data_only=True, keep_links=False)`

What is interesting is that with other excel file I do not get this error... Therefore I am curious what is the problem with a completely "new excel", with one sheet and one table that I am trying to read... and other excel into which I just copied the values, not the whole sheet the code works.

Comment: Without an example .xls file which contains this error it is hard to give an answer. The best we can do is guess.

Comment: The file is possibly invalid. Can't say more without looking at it.

Comment: The file is somehow invalid, but what puzzled me is that when I took the sheet into another excel and run the python everything worked just fine... It must be something in that particular excel file, but I still have no idea what...

Comment: And thanks for your time guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give this an educated guess:

- The last line (`ValueError: Value must be one of {0, 1, 2, [...]`) tells us that *some* value in the Excel file contains an unsupported value.
- Going up the traceback we see this: `[...] openpyxl\styles\alignment.py", line 59, in __init__` which leads me to believe that this is *something* to do with text alignment.
- With this in mind, the last-line becomes a bit more interesting: `Value must be one of {0, 1, [...] 179, 180}`: The possible values range from 0 to 180. So could this possibly be related to text-rotation?

Could it be that the Excel file which works does not have any rotated text, but the file which fails *does*? If yes, can you try to remove the rotation and try again?

Answer (score 0):

rename the file & save it will helps you to load the workbook
or
use read_only = True,

```
wb = load_workbook(filename,read_only = True)
```