# Cannot convert dataframe to excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm trying to print a column of dataframe I collected to an excel file.
but I get the error `raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))`.

My code:

```
node1 = (data[data['equal'] == True])
node2 = (data[data['equal'] == False])
ws['I1'] = node1['node2']
ws['J1'] = node1['#node1']
wb.save("a.xlsx")
```

[image: dataframe]

[image: excel]

I'd like to print to my column I1 everything in node1 when the equal is false.

Comment: may be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816796/what-does-this-python-openpyxl-valueerror-mean)

Comment: are you using a pandas dataframe? why not use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)?

Comment: well, i'd like to print out the dataframe to an already existing excel file since i wanted to keep original formatting