# What does this openpyxl "ValueError" mean when loading a workbook?

Tags: python, openpyxl

In Jupyter Notebook, I am attempting to run the following code to open an existing XLSX file with pivot tables.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook('TEMPLATE.xlsx')
```

This ends up throwing a value error, to do with pivot tables:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 wb=load_workbook('TEMPLATE.xlsx')
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py
> in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
> 315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
> 316                         data_only, keep_links)
> --> 317     reader.read()
> 318     return reader.wb
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py
> in read(self)
> 280         self.read_theme()
> 281         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
> --> 282         self.read_worksheets()
> 283         self.parser.assign_names()
> 284         if not self.read_only:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py
> in read_worksheets(self)
> 266                 src = self.archive.read(pivot_path)
> 267                 tree = fromstring(src)
> --> 268                 pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
> 269                 pivot.cache = self.parser.pivot_caches[pivot.cacheId]
> 270                 ws.add_pivot(pivot)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py
> in from_tree(cls, node)
> 81             if hasattr(desc, 'from_tree'):
> 82                 #descriptor manages conversion
> ---> 83                 obj = desc.from_tree(el)
> 84             else:
> 85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py
> in from_tree(self, node)
> 83
> 84     def from_tree(self, node):
> ---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
> 86
> 87
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py
> in (.0)
> 83
> 84     def from_tree(self, node):
> ---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
> 86
> 87
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py
> in from_tree(cls, node)
> 101                 attrib[tag] = obj
> 102
> --> 103         return cls(**attrib)
> 104
> 105
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\pivot\table.py
> in **init**(self, scope, type, priority, pivotAreas, extLst)
> 479                  extLst=None,
> 480                 ):
> --> 481         self.scope = scope
> 482         self.type = type
> 483         self.priority = priority
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py
> in **set**(self, instance, value)
> 126     def **set**(self, instance, value):
> 127         if value not in self.values:
> --> 128             raise ValueError(self.**doc**)
> 129         super(Set, self).**set**(instance, value)
> 130
>
> ValueError: Value must be one of {'data', 'selection', 'field'}

Has anyone encountered this before or found a workaround? I cannot open the file in read-only mode because I need to edit a sheet which is the source for the data tables. However, opening in read-only mode allows me to open the file.

Comment: Is this somehow helping you? [What does this python openpyxl “ValueError” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816796/what-does-this-python-openpyxl-valueerror-mean)

Comment: since there's no much to go on here I would recommend verifying your data is valid for a openpyxl workbook